# Prototyping with IRobot roomba

Tags: irobot-create, roomba

For a project I am building a Tele-Op Robot using the IRobot's Roomba as my drivetrain. In order for my robot to work, I need an extra castor. IRobot provides .stl and .stp files for me to use and I used them and printed the files. (The file I printed was from this link: [Create® 2 Bin Modification](http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Create_2_Bin_Modification.pdf).

This file is a new part to the drivetrain to allow another caster.

And I downloaded the first link called "[Full bin bottom with caster mount](http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/Files/About/STEM/Create/c2binbottom.stl)"

The piece was great but it made the castor a different height then the wheels. I was wondering if anyone had this file but saved as something different so I can edit it in preferably Solidworks. I was on the phone with IRobot for over 2 hours today and they told me to post here. So please help!!!! :)

Answer (score 3):

The caster shaft can potentially not seat right causing canting of the robot.

Can you share pictures of your print? I have had good luck with printing the files posted on the iRobot thingiverse page.

Answer (score 2):

Are you having trouble importing the file? I'm not sure what the problem you're having is. You can edit the file in Solidworks; just import the STL, then edit the file.